# How to generate smartsheet access token giving access to only single sheet

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v1

I want to share a particular sheet for an automation job. Is there someway to restrict the access using access token to only one sheet.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Smartsheet access token is *owned by* a specific Smartsheet user, and therefore can only be used to access the Smartsheet data that the user has been explicitly granted access to in Smartsheet. You can therefore facilitate the scenario you've described by doing the following:

1. Login to Smartsheet via Smartsheet web UI (as a user that has permissions to create new users) and create a new user within your account.
2. Grant the new user the appropriate level of access to the sheet(s) that they should be able to access.
3. Logout of Smartsheet and then login as the new user you just created.
4. While logged in as the new user, generate an access token belonging to that user, by following the instructions here in the docs: https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#raw-token-requests.

   - When used in API requests, this access token will provide the same level access that the user (token owner) has explicitly been granted in Smartsheet. e.g., if you granted the user read access to a single sheet in Smartsheet, then the API token can only be used to read data in that one sheet.
5. Use the API access token in API requests where you want permissions restricted to the same level of access that its owner has been granted in Smartsheet.